# Distributed transaction with multiple database servers seems unreliable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jta, distributed-transactions

After googling for some days i got to understand something about JTA and

then wrote an application that uses JTA, JDBC and MySQL server for performing distributed transaction. 
Below is my code.

We are using 3 different database servers and res1, res2 and res3(these are 3 different XAResources) denote them respectively.

```
try{
    res1.start(xid1, XAResource.TMNOFLAGS);
    dao.addEmployee(e, con);
    res1.end(xid1, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);

    res2.start(xid2, XAResource.TMNOFLAGS);
    dao.addDepartment(d, tournamentCon);
    res2.end(xid2, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);
    res3.start(xid3, XAResource.TMNOFLAGS);
    dao.addAsset(a, testCon);
    res3.end(xid3, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);
    int result1 = res1.prepare(xid1);
    int result2 = res2.prepare(xid2);
    int result3 = res3.prepare(xid3);

    if(result1 == XAResource.XA_OK && result2 == XAResource.XA_OK && 
    result3 == XAResource.XA_OK) {
    res1.commit(xid1, false);
    res2.commit(xid2, false);
        res3.commit(xid3, false);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    res1.rollback(xid1);
    res2.rollback(xid2);
    res3.rollback(xid3);
}
```

Now, the problem with this approach is :-

let's say during res2.commit or res3.commit, there is an exception 
then the commits which have already been done i.e res1.commit, coult not be rolled back

but we want all these trxs to be done completely or nothing at all.

Could someone please let me know how to do this?

FYI : we are not using any application server.

Please also let me know what a transaction manager is ? Is it a s/w component which needs to be used explicitly or the code that i have posted is what would be called a transaction manager.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is way too broad for someone who doesn't know what a transaction manager is. I recommend you do some research yourself, then ask for clarification on specific things. For example you seem to have missed the point of distributed transactions, which is to either commit or rollback **all** sub-transactions. That's not up to you to handle.

Comment: @Kayaman..thanks for pointing this out..commit or rollback all sub-transactions don't need to be handled by the application developer..i have been researching on this topic for the past 3 4 days..but i feel there's lack of resources on net..

Comment: There's plenty of resources on distributed transactions, it's not a new invention. It's not that there's a lack of resources, it's just that you aren't finding them. Finding information is the most important skill of a programmer, pretty much all the knowledge is online already (unlike 20+ years ago).